# What is the best solution to attaching a then onto a promise multi-level down the call stack?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, callstack

Consider such a senario:

```
function func_topmost(){
    ...
    func_layer1();
    pseudo_code for some actions here; // an action that needs to run AFTER the promise in func_layer2 fulfilled.
}

function func_layer1(){
    ...
    func_layer2();
}

function func_layer2(){
    var the_vital_promise = $.post('very_slow_backend_response', data);
    return the_vital_promise;
}
```

The above is just an illustration. In reality the call stack could be even deeper and there is always a possibility that another layer of function will be introduced to the call stacks in future development.

My question is, what is the best practice to make sure that the actions in the topmost layer function that dependent on the fulfillment of the promise in the bottom layer attached properly?

Right now I can think of making all the functions in the calling chain `async function` all the way to the bottom. I am not sure if this is the right solution, and it makes later maintenance very rigid.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow—how does making the functions `async` make it more rigid? You don’t *need* to do it that way, though; you only need to make sure you return the promises, like in Psi’s answer. You could combine that with making `func_topmost` an `async` function to simplify the flow, if you wanted.

Comment: Maybe we're dealing with an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: @ Aankhen, The reason I would call it 'rigid' is that if you or one of your team ever forget to return the promise when introducing a middle layer of new func in future development, assuming it would return nothing just like other funcs, then your promise chain is broken. And there seems no way to enforce this rule in yourself or others.

Comment: You don’t need to return promises from `async` functions. `async function foo() { return 3; }` returns a promise that’s fulfilled with the value 3. It’s less rigid than non-`async` functions in that you don’t have to remember to wrap things in promises and deal with them using `then`/`catch` (instead being able to use `await` and `try`/`catch`), and equally rigid in that if you want to return a value to a function higher up in the stack, you have to return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have multiple normal functions calling each other, and all of a sudden the one on top of a stack happens to handle some asynchronous task and you are looking for a way to solve the issue with minimum code change. There are 3 ways that I am aware of to handle that and 2 of them are already mentioned, but I think they have some drawbacks.

**1. Returning a promise**

- *Will break the code structure*
- *Requires change in all functions*

**2. Async/await**

```
async function func_topmost(){
    const data = await func_layer1();
    pseudo_code for some actions here; // an action that needs to run AFTER the promise in func_layer2 fulfilled.
}

function func_layer1(){
    const promise = func_layer2();
    return promise;
}

function func_layer2(){
    var the_vital_promise = $.post('very_slow_backend_response', data);
    return the_vital_promise;
}
```

- *less code change than returning a promise but more code in compiled bundle*
- *Requires change in all functions*

**3. Dispatch an event**

This seems to be the best way of handling the problem to me if you have many functions stacked. You can use events library if you are on Node, or custom DOM events if the environment is the browser. This way you only need to change the first and the last function (if the functions in between doesn't depend on promise completion) and the code structure is kept.

```
function func_layer2(){
    var the_vital_promise = $.post('very_slow_backend_response', data)
    .then(res => {
         events.emit('customEvent');
     });
    return the_vital_promise;
}

function func_topmost(){
    ...
    events.on('customEvent', () => {
         pseudo_code for some actions here; // an action that needs to run AFTER the promise in func_layer2 fulfilled.
    });
    func_layer1();
}
```

Comment: I think your number 2 also requires adding a return of that specific promise object to each functions along the call stack, or otherwise the async function would just add its void promise, which is not desired. Isn't it? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Edited answer, that's how your code would look like with `async/await`

Comment: For the async/await solution, do you really need to make the middle layer, which is `func_layer()` a `async` function as well? I think you only need to make sure it returns what it gets from the next layer. Is it correct?

Comment: if you are awaiting inside function, that function must be `async`

Comment: Yes, but the `awaiting` part only occurs at the topmost layer, the middle layer(s) just relay the promise. Do we really need to make each and every func an async along the call stack?

Comment: You are right, functions in the middle of stack doesn't need to await if they don't need the data promise resolves. They can just return promise as is. I'll edit that

Answer (score 0):

If I get your intent correct, it should be as easy as just returning the promise to the topmost function and calling `then` on that promise:

```
function func_topmost(){
    ...
    func_layer1().then(function(param){
        // Your action here after resolving the promise
    }).catch(function(){
        // Your code on rejection of the promise
    });

}

function func_layer1(){
    ...
    return func_layer2();
}

function func_layer2(){
    var the_vital_promise = $.post('very_slow_backend_response', data);
    return the_vital_promise;
}
```

A second way, if you want to chain func_layer1 (which would have been nice to know in advance) is to provide the actions as callbacks:

```
function func_topmost(){
    func_layer1( 
        function(){
            // Code on completion
        },
        function(){
            // Code on rejection
        });
 }

function func_layer1( onResolve, onReject ){
    func_layer2().then( onResolve, onReject );
}

...
```

Comment: What if for `func_layer1()` you'd like to return `this` instead of the result of `func_layer2()`, to make itself chainable? That's where I found this route inflexible.

Comment: Then just return an object:`{ref:this, promise: func_layer2()}`. Where's the problem? You then have to chain it a little bit differently but ok. Chainability in fact is a little abuse of the return value of functions.

Comment: Another way would be to provide the callback function as a parameter of func1